# ununderstandable behavior subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout) and os.system(cmd)

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system, datalog, clingo

I use an external command inside a python script using firstly:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

then i get the stdout.

The problem is that the result of this external command when executing it inside the script is not the same if i execute it directly in the command line.

I use then `os.system(cmd)`, but the same problem.

Is this instructions in python use some buffers?

How can i explain the difference between the two results (command line and inside the script).

I'm using this tool as a local command from comman line after installing it:

https://potassco.org/clingo/run/

I use some file as input like this one:

```
edge("s1","s3").

edge("s2","s4").

edge("s3","s4").

path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y). % x and y are strings

path(X,Z) :- path(X,Y), path(Y,Z).

:- path(X,Y), path(Y,X). %cyclic path.
```

To do it the tool generate a model like this :

```
edge("s1","s3") edge("s2","s4") edge("s3","s4") path("s1","s3") path("s2","s4") path("s3","s4") path("s1","s4")
SATISFIABLE
```

When i call the command inside my python script it doesn't compute all the model, it generate an incomplete model. This problem appear only in the big examples, which requires the computation of a large model . That's why i'm asking if this commands : subprocess.Popen and os.system use some buffers...

Comment: could you elaborate on the command and what the differences are?

Comment: The difference is in the output, i have a command which generate some output in a file. For example when i execute the command directly it generate a file with the size 10KB but if i call it inside a python script it gives me a file with size 8KB. When i review the output i release that it missed some outputs, i dont understand why!

Comment: That may depend on the command you're using, what environment it's running from, what is its current working directory and a plethora of other things. You haven't provided enough information for us to be able to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Im using this tool as a local command after installing it : https://potassco.org/clingo/run/ .

Comment: @zwer i edited my post, please get a look now

Comment: @torresmateo i edited my post, please get a look now

Comment: This smells like a buffering problem. Could you provide the code for reading the command output of `subprocess.Popen`? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645847/attempting-two-way-communication-between-python2-7-and-asp-writing-contents-of/43672407#43672407) might be relevant.

Comment: How do you "get" the stdout? With the method communicate()?

Comment: @tkrennwa: p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                while True:
                    output = str(p.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8"))
                    res += output

Comment: As written in the [documentation for Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen): "`bufsize` will be supplied as the corresponding argument to the `open()` function when creating the `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` pipe file objects". The buffer defaults to the system buffering settings. [Furthermore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr): "Warning: Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process."