# Call external command from python without using neither os.system nor subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, os.system

Is there any other way to call external command from python without using neither os.system nor subprocess.

This is related to my previous question [ununderstandable behavior subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout) and os.system(cmd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394697/ununderstandable-behavior-subprocess-popencmd-stdout-and-os-systemcmd?noredirect=1#comment91737614_52394697) The problem is that os.system and subprocess doesn't return all expected output.

Comment: you have `os.execv`-like functions. why do you need to avoid the above?

Comment: Can you provide some context as to why you need that?

Comment: @EliKorvigo i modified my question with more details

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i modified my question with more details

Comment: It sounds that you need https://github.com/yuce/pyswip or https://github.com/f0ma/pyswip3 . You will have python to prolog binding without communication over stdio.

Comment: Is this on a Unix/Linux system? If so, read up on tty:s and how they work. Sometimes programs detects if they do not have a terminal connected to them and behave differently if they don't. This could be such a situaiton. In that case you can use `pty` to emulate a terminal  or, most likely depending on the situation `pexpect` to make your subprocess behave the way you want it to.

Comment: @JohanL Nop, it is windows 10